# open_basedir | ISPManager trying to turn it off or set it as "none"

Tags: php, laravel, config

I built a website on my computer via XAMPP and it's working fine.
When I moved it to the server, the site works perfectly, just one page didn't work. I got this error:

> is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/embed-cookies.5ba923a873d47) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/lielz/data:) ".

I change the value for the `open_basedir` to none in the server and even tried to turn it off. Any suggestions?

- PHP 7.2
- Laravel 5.6